# Cannot install Zend Debugger on 64-bit Windows 10

Tags: php, windows, 32bit-64bit, zend-debugger

I'm having trouble installing Zend Debugger on Windows 10 64-bit. I have PHP 8.0.1 installed, 64-bit version.

I have downloaded the ZendDebugger.dll from Zend (also 64-bit) and placed in my "ext" folder, and the php.ini file updated accordingly.

When I try running php from the command-line I get:

`PHP Warning: Failed loading Zend extension 'ZendDebugger.dll' (tried: ext\ZendDebugger.dll (%1 is not a valid Win32 application), ...`

This indicates that it has found the file, but cannot utilise it as it is the wrong architecture. This error message implies the .dll file is indeed 64-bit, but I do not understand why a 32-bit version is expected. Running php -i from command-line, and phpinfo() under Apache both suggest everything is 64-bit.

I have trawled the internet for an answer but have turned up nothing.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you have solved the problem.

I solved this moving the ZendDebugger.dll to php8.1 folder, not ext folder,
and adding the flowing lines after the "extension=zend_test in the php .ini file.

Windows non-thread safe: zend_extension="D:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.4.26\ZendDebugger.dll"
zend_debugger.allow_hosts=127.0.0.1

**Change the ip address if you debug in remote server.